# Getting feedburner subscriber count with jQuery and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, feedburner

I need to display the total number of the feedburner subscribers without PHP. The script should be work in a standard HTML / jQuery page.

Something like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var username = "feeder_username";   
            var feedburnerurl = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20xml%20WHERE%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Ffeedburner.google.com%2Fapi%2Fawareness%2F1.0%2FGetFeedData%3Furi%3D"+ username +"%26format%3Djson%26callback%3D'&format=json&callback=?";   

            $.getJSON(feedburnerurl, function(data) {                                             
                feed_count = data(['query']['results']['rsp']['feed']['entry'].circulation);  
                $('#feed').html(feed_count);
            }); 

        });
```

Do you have a working solution?

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: what's wrong with what you've tried then? I don't see any PHP there.

Comment: i am not that good at jquery. i think it should something similar to that code, but obvious, that isn't working, otherwise where is the purpose of the question?

Comment: well, that code does a number of things. At what specific point does the failure occur? What does work?

Comment: i need to display the total nr of subscribers. i don't know how to do it. you can forget about code. do you know an working solution?

Comment: No, but I was happy to help you debug what code you do have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feedburner API is no longer available. According to this:
https://developers.google.com/feedburner/

So you can't do this anymore..

Comment: Nope, at least with Javascript as you asked in the question, not really.